# SQLite3 Creating ID's

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table that contains an id field.

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info('posts')
   ...> ;
0|id|integer|1||1
1|uuid|varchar(36)|1||0
2|title|varchar(150)|1||0
```

When I insert a new entry into the table what is the advised approach for the id column. Is there an auto increment option or do I need to get the last id number and increment by 1 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert a `null` value to the `id` column and an identifier will be generated for you - it is the `PRIMARY KEY` as indicated by the last `1` in the table info.

Further reading: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html